# creating custom pages with jquery php

Tags: ajax

i have 3 tabs at top of page i.e

home | profile | +

now i want that user can create their own custom page while click the (+) icon/button...!! how can i do that with php ajax

Comment: Sounds like you're trying to do a CMS of sorts, correct? That is a lengthy topic....

Answer (score 0):

One way may be like this:

1: When + link is clicked, you prompt the user for entering title of the page to be created.
2: User enters page name; request goes to a php script via ajax
3: PHP scripts creates a page in db with submitted title.
4: With ajax response; you redirect user to new created page and edit it.

There can be many solutions to that though.

Comment: but i want to create a new tab with user defined title and user should stay on that page

Comment: logic will be almost similar; you can modify the steps accordingly